# Save runtime created table data into database

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I create one form which includes two text box & one submit button,when i enter number of rows & columns and click on submit button that number of rows & columns table structure would be generated on form,when i enter data into that table I want to save that data into database.  please if you have any demo example then please give Its urgent for me Thanks in advance..

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
 include_once "dreportCreation.php";
        {       
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                function displaydata($column,$rows)             
                    {       
                        echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";           
                        for($i = 0;$i<$_POST['column'];$i++)       
                        { 
                            echo "<tr>".$j."</tr>";                              
                            for($j = 0; $j <$_POST['rows'];$j++)         
                                {

                                    echo "<td>" ."<input type=\"text\" name='$i'>"."</td>"; 
                                }
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                    }
        }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>aa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="reportCreation" method="post" action="dd.php">
                        <label for='Table'>Define Table</label>
                        <label for='rows'>Row</label>
                        <input type="text" name="column"></input>
                        <label for='column'>Column</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rows"></input>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="displaydata();">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code, first, you are defining a php function called `displaydata`, but are calling a javascript function with the same name when submit gets clicked. So the page reloads and sends the inputs outside the form (and before `<html>` tag), provided you are calling the function anywhere inside php ...
As for the inputs, you should create an array inputs for each column, something like the following:

```
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";           
for($i = 0;$i<$_POST['column'];$i++)       
{ 
    echo "<tr>".$j."</tr>";                              
    for($j = 0; $j <$_POST['rows'];$j++)         
    {
          echo "<td>" ."<input type=\"text\" name='column_$i[$j]'>"."</td>"; // you should provide a beter name than simly a number ... just saying :)
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

This way, when you get information on php you'll get an array on `$_POST['i']['j']` and will be able to save them all. Otherhow, you would only get the last input of each column only.

A working example could be:

```
<?php
 include_once "dreportCreation.php";
 function displaydata($column,$rows)             
 {       
      echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";           
      for($i = 0;$i<$_POST['column'];$i++)       
      { 
            echo "<tr>".$j."</tr>";                              
            for($j = 0; $j <$_POST['rows'];$j++)         
            {
                  echo "<td>" ."<input type=\"text\" name='column_$i[$j]'>"."</td>"; 
            }
       }
       echo "</table>";
  }
  ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>aa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="reportCreation" method="post" action="dd.php">
                        <label for='Table'>Define Table</label>
                        <label for='rows'>Row</label>
                        <input type="text" name="column"></input>
                        <label for='column'>Column</label>
                        <input type="text" name="rows"></input>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

<?Php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) displaydata(); // Show data INSIDE form
?>

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

By the way, you still have to detect, on post, that data is sent to be saved. Something like `if (isset($_POST['column_0'])) { //start saving stuff }` would do just fine